# Passing NSInteger variable to NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Why does this not work:

```
NSInteger temp = 20;
[userSettingsFromFile setObject:temp forKey:@"aTemp"];
```

but this does:

```
[userSettingsFromFile setObject:@"someObject" forKey:@"aTemp"];
```

How can I use the `NSInteger` variable?

Comment: Your title is incorrect -- according to your sample code, you're using an NSMutableDictionary, not an NSMutableArray.

Comment: I have edited the title. Anyway, the problem may also arise with NSMutableArray and with any collection in general.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`NSInteger` isn't an object -- it's simply typecast to `int` on 32-bit or `long` on 64-bit. Since `NSDictionary` can only store objects, you need to wrap the integer into an object before you can store it. Try this:

```
NSInteger temp = 20;
[userSettingsFromFile setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp] 
                         forKey:@"aTemp"];
```

Comment: To get it back out of the NSDictionay you need to use something like NSInteger temp = [[userSettingsFromFile objectForKey:@"aTemp"]  integerValue];

Answer (score 6):

In order to store numbers in collections, you have to wrap them up in an `NSNumber` instance.

```
double aDouble = 20.3d;
NSInteger anInt = 20;

NSNumber *aWrappedDouble = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:aDouble];
NSNumber *aWrappedInt = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:anInt];

NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aWrappedDouble, aWrappedInt, nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you pass through setObject has to be derived from `NSObject`. `NSInteger` is not, it's a simple int typedef. In your 2nd example you use `NSString`, which is derived from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger is synonym for long integer.What follows is how NSInteger is defined:

```
#if __LP64__ || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

NSNumber is an Objective-C class, a subclass of NSValue to be specific. You can create an NSNumber object from a signed or unsigned char, short int, int, long int, long long int, float, double or BOOL

One of the primary distinctions is that you can use NSNumber in collections, such as NSArray, where an object is required. For example, if you need to add a float into an NSArray, you would first need to create an NSNumber object from the float:

```
float percentage = 40.5;
```

...
// Create NSNumber object, which can now be inserted into an    NSArray

```
NSNumber *percentageObject = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percentage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction: Whatever is passed through `setObject:` do not have to be derived from the `NSObject` class, but it must conform to the `NSObject` protocol, that defines `retain` and `release`.

It can be confusing, but classes and protocols have different name spaces. And there is a both a class and a protocol named `NSObject`, the class `NSObject` conforms to the protocol `NSObject`. There is one more root class, the `NSProxy` class that also conforms to the `NSObject` protocol.

This is important, because otherwise proxies could not be used in collections and auto release pools, while still having a lightweight proxy root class.

Answer (score 0):

Referred to @Matt Ball's answer: NSInteger isn't an object -- it's simply typecast to int on 32-bit or long on 64-bit. Since NSDictionary can only store objects, you need to wrap the integer into an object before you can store it.

So, in case of **Swift**, this is how you do it:

```
let temp:NSInteger = yourInteger.hashValue
```

Answer (score -1):

just use: `$(variable)` syntax to convert primitive type to object.

Comment: Correct syntax is `@(var)`