# How to pass NSUInteger into NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to send an integer into an NSDictionary as a parameter.  For some reason, I am unable to send an NSString containing the value of the integer since a string can't be compared to an integer (this is in my other code).  As a result, I am forced to send in (instead of an NSString) an `NSUInteger` or `NSInteger` into the `NSDictionary`.

This leads me to my problem, since an NS(U)Integer is NOT an object, and cannot be inserted into an NSDictionary.  So, my code is as follows:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"index":indexPath.row]};
```

Now, my question is... how should I format this NS(U)Integer into an object?

The marked duplicate question DOES NOT answer my question in the way that I want.

Comment: please search before you ask something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339394/passing-nsinteger-variable-to-nsmutabledictionary-or-nsmutablearray

Comment: "And... PLEASE don't vote down on the post." – but hell yeah. This question is poorly researched (if any). You should have googled it.

Comment: Grr... That didn't work either..... I tried it.. trust me.

Comment: @JackThomas [Google: "insert nsuinteger in nsdictionary"](http://google.com/search?q=insert+nsuinteger+in+nsdictionary) —> and the **second hit** is a [Stack Overflow question from 2009](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339394/passing-nsinteger-variable-to-nsmutabledictionary-or-nsmutablearray).

Comment: Plus, voting down won't affect my rep...  I have 1 anyway.

Comment: I already told you.  That DIDN'T WORK!

Comment: Gee.  Even that didn't help my parameter.... that was useless.

Comment: @JackThomas the accepted answer to that question is functionally **identical** to the answer you are going to accept here. It is not possible that this answer worked but that one didn't.

Comment: And how come I can't close this post ANYWAY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html) class for doing the same:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"index":[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:indexPath.row]};
```

Or in [Modern Objective C](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"index":@(indexPath.row)};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way using objective c 2.0 style

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"index":@(indexPath.row)]};
```

this will create object as NSNumber internally!